# How to change the font / typeface of a button in RemoteViews of an Android Widget?

Tags: android, widget, android-remoteview

How can I change the font / typeface of a button in an Android widget? When working with *normal* view is this no problem:

```
// Within the app
Button myButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.myAppButton);
myButton.setTypeface(someTypeface);
```

However, when working with a widget, views cannot be accessed directly but only via `RemoteViews`:

```
// Widget
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetContent);
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.myWidgetButton, "Some Text");
```

**Is it somehow possible to set the typeface of the remote button as well?**

Comment: do you tried this?
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "robotobold.ttf");
myButton.setTypeface(font);

Comment: Thanks, but did you read the question? ;-) What you wrote works perfectly when using buttons directly as I described in the first example in my question. However, when working with a widget I **cannot** access the views directly but only via `RemoteViews`....

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the typeface of *TextView* in *RemoteView*.

To check properties that can be changed in *RemoteView*, go to `android.widget.Button` and `android.widget.TextView` classes and check all methods with annotation `@android.view.RemotableViewMethod`. As you can see, *setTypeface* method has no annotation, so it can **not** be changed in *RemoteView*.